# How to deploy JavaScript file changes to PROD in CRM Dynamics as Patch?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I am new to CRM, and I had made some changes in (.js files) for crm test environment and want to deploy changes to PROD environment as a patch.

I don't find any example related to JavaScript files.

Can anyone help me how to deploy changes to PROD environment?

Comment: Inside Dynamics CRM / 365 CE the way to move customizations between environments is by using solutions

Comment: Can you share me the steps on how to do it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview

Comment: can we create patch for the modified JavaScript files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Give [this blogpost](https://carldesouza.com/how-patching-of-solutions-works-in-the-power-platform/) a read and follow the below steps.

- Create managed solution patch 1.0.1.2 (this has JS web resource)
- Update the source org and export 1.0.1.2
- Deploy patch 1.0.1.2 into to target
- Clone solution and deploy to target